# call method only on rx_tap event

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have a basic problem with rxswift.
I have a login screen that should call my login method inside view model when and only when I tap the login button

```
        loginButton.rx_tap
        .doOn({[unowned self] _ in
            self.loginButton.enabled = false
        })
        .flatMap({[unowned self] in self.loginModel.login() })
        .subscribeNext({ [weak self] login  in
            self?.loginButton.enabled = true

            guard login?.result == 1 else {
                self?.showErrorWithMessage(login!.message)
                return;
            }

           // Logged in!
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Looks fine, but if the login failed because of credential not valid and the user restart typing on to the text field the call to loginModel.login() is fired again...

Inside the view model there is also:

```
    var credentials : Driver<(String, String)> {
    return Driver.combineLatest(userNameDriver.distinctUntilChanged(), passwordDriver.distinctUntilChanged()) { usr, pwd in
        return (usr, pwd)
    }
}

var usrValid : Driver<Bool> {
    get {
        return userNameDriver
            .throttle(0.5)
            .filterEmpty()
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .map { ($0.rangeOfString("@") != nil) || ($0.utf8.count == 0) }
    }
}

var pwdValid : Driver<Bool> {
    get {
        return passwordDriver
        .throttle(0.5)
        .filterEmpty()
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .map { ($0.utf8.count > 5) || ($0.utf8.count == 0) }
    }
}

var usernameBorderColor : Observable<UIColor>!
var passwordBorderColor : Observable<UIColor>!

var credentialValid : Driver<Bool> {
    return Driver.combineLatest(usrValid, pwdValid) { usr, pwd in
        return (usr && pwd)
    }
}
```

Someone can help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Hey! I can't to reproduce this bug because it non-obvious for me. Can you create simple project with your login on Github? I'll clone it, help you to fix it and write solution in this topic.

Comment: Here you can find the project: https://github.com/jerrygdm/RxTap_Issue I added just a sample just to look at the issue. If you enter in the textfield user and pass and after you tap login you have a reply based on the result....for example you write wrong credentials and tap login you get the result in the subscribeNext, but if you try to write new credentials the signal starts one more time....I just want to cancel the previous signal and to fire a new one only when the button login is tapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reviewed your project. The problem was not a very good architecture of your ViewModel. I fix one using example from [RxSwift repo](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GitHubSignup/UsingVanillaObservables/GithubSignupViewModel1.swift). See your new view model below:

```
class LoginViewModel
{
let validatedUsername: Driver<Bool>
let validatedPassword: Driver<Bool>

// Is login button enabled
let loginEnabled: Observable<Bool>

// Has user log in
let loggedIn: Observable<Login>

var usernameBorderColor : Observable<UIColor>
var passwordBorderColor : Observable<UIColor>

init(input: (
    userName: Driver<String>,
    password: Driver<String>,
    loginClick: Observable<Void>
    ),
    dependency: (
    RxMoyaProvider<APIProvider>
    )
    ) {

    let credentials = Driver.combineLatest(input.userName, input.password) { ($0, $1) }

    validatedUsername = input.userName.map { $0.rangeOfString("@") != nil }
    validatedPassword = input.password.map { $0.utf8.count > 5 }

    usernameBorderColor = validatedUsername.asObservable()
        .map{valid in
            return valid ? UIColor.clearColor() : UIColor.redColor()
    }
    passwordBorderColor = validatedPassword.asObservable()
        .map{valid in
            return valid ? UIColor.clearColor() : UIColor.redColor()
    }

    loginEnabled = Observable.combineLatest(
        validatedUsername.asObservable(),
        validatedPassword.asObservable()
    )   { username, password in
        username &&
        password
        }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .shareReplay(1)

    loggedIn = input.loginClick.withLatestFrom(credentials)
        .flatMap { username, password -> Observable<Login> in
            var resultLogin : Login
            if username == "test@" && password == "123123" {
                resultLogin = Login(result: 1, message: "OK")
            }
            else {
                resultLogin = Login(result: 0, message: "KO")
            }

            return Observable.create { observer in
                observer.onNext(resultLogin)
                observer.onCompleted()

                return AnonymousDisposable {

                }
            }
        }
        .retry()
        .shareReplay(1)
    }
}
```

Also you have to change your login view controller:

```
let viewModel = LoginViewModel(
        input: (
            userName: userTextField.rx_text.asDriver(),
            password: pwdTextField.rx_text.asDriver(),
            loginClick: loginButton.rx_tap.asObservable()
        ),
        dependency: (
            apiProvider
        )
    )

    viewModel.loginEnabled
        .subscribeNext { [weak self] valid  in
            self?.loginButton.enabled = valid
            self?.loginButton.alpha = valid ? 1.0 : 0.5
        }
        .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)

    viewModel.loggedIn
        .subscribeNext { login  in

            print(login.message)

            guard login.result == 1 else {
                // Show error
                return;
            }


            }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

I created pull request, you have to accept it and see full source code. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much, I just merge, this evening I have a look at your code :)

Comment: @Svyatoslav This really helped me. Thank you for such an elaborated answer.

Comment: @Danny Thanks. Happy to help.